# Where is the .cod file placed when the BlackBerry Widget is built from Eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, simulator

I am experimenting with various mobile platforms, and this is my first day with BB.

I am using Web Plug in 2.0.0 with SDK 1.0.0. As I am trying to run one of the samples in the simulator (5.0.0.469, Storem 2 9550)

When I run the BB widget, I got the following in the eclipse console, but I could not find the .cod file to be loaded to the simulator. Please help!! By the way  I am using xp and jdk6 update 18

BUILDING upComingAppointment
cmd.exe /c bbwp C:\tshenWorkSpace\blackberry\upComingAppointment\b uild\upComingAppointment.zip /o C:\tshenWorkSpace\blackberry\upComingAppointment\b uild
BUILD SUCCESS

---

BUILDING upComingAppointmentcmd.exe /c bbwp C:\tshenWorkSpace\blackberry\upComingAppointment\b uild\upComingAppointment.zip /o C:\tshenWorkSpace\blackberry\upComingAppointment\b uildBUILD SUCCESS******************************************

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Widget development on BlackBerry but looking at the docs it says the COD is saved in the /bin folder that you created when you compiled the widget.